# Por que solo me llama a un metodo en la pagina por defecto??? JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto utilizando Jsf.

El problema es que al llamar a un método de un Bean  por ejemplo `#{pruebaBean.test()}` solo me devuelve correctamente el resultado en la primer pagina que ejecuta el proyecto, osea la pagina por defecto seteada en `web.xml`, al cambiar de pagina simplemente me devuelve `#{prueba.test()}` tal cual.

Tengo un archivo de configuración de lo `beans face-config.xml` con lo siguiente:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>pruebaBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>Beans.PruebaBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

y un Bean simple y básico de prueba:

```
public class PruebaBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of UsuarioBean
 */
public PruebaBean() {
}
public String test(){
return "prueba";
}
```

}

Deduzco que falta algo en la configuracion para que abarque a todas las paginas, pero no se que es , si me ayudaran les agradeceria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que veo es que tienes definido el ámbito del bean como request . Entoces los valores de ese bean están disponibles en una única solicitud http .

Intentan cambiar el scope de tu bean a session y se mantendrá en todas las páginas